# Android executing SU commands in background?

Tags: android, service, broadcast, toast, su

I'm writing an android app that sets the max frequency, governor etc.. when the screen turns off. To do it i have a service running that receives screen on/off broadcast intents. When the screen off event fires, I read from the shared preferences and set whatever is set by the user with this function

```
public static void writeFile(String file, String content) {
    try {
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes("echo '" + content + "' > '" + file + "'");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then when the screen turns back on, i revert the system to its previous state by rewriting the files. Everything is working nicely, working as intended.

The problem is i'm noticing some lag when turning the screen on/off. Also when i turn the screen on, i see the toast message from SuperUser "App was granted su access", and it pops up once for every command. Is there a way to hide that toast message? I haven't found any way to hide a toast message from another activity. I know they can be disabled in the superuser app, but that's not ideal. I read you can write your own superuser binary but that sounds alot more complicated than simple java programming... also sounds like it could lead to security problems.

Basically i'm asking what's the best way to do this, so that it's as non-invasive to the user as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used su, but I think if you don't close the stream every time it should only display toast once.